# handle menu on masterpage

Tags: asp.net, menu

I have a masterpage and a menu with contentpages. If I go to content page A.aspx I want the menu item o have the css class selected. If I gi to B.aspx I want the B menu item inside the master page to appear seleced(have the cssClass='seleced'). How can I implement this easily on an asp.net master page?

Comment: Are you using .net menu control? How are you rendering menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research this doesn't seem to be the easiest thing to accomplish unless your building your site as MS intended.

If you have a web.sitemap(xml-)file then its really easy because you get that functionality by default.

That means that you must add a datasource to your menu and use the sitemap-file as datasource. I don't know how it works with other datasources but I really hope ASP.NET is smart enough to fix it.

You could check [this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/305w735z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for a walkthrough

Comment: Please note that I'm assuming here that you're using a menu-control, which might be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use menu control with [Css friendly](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/)

The selected one will be attached a css class AspNet-Menu-Selected.